How can I aquire the preferred set (Argumentation theory) in Answer Set Programming (ASP)?
I am a beginner in answer set programming and wonder how I would go about aquiring the admissible set. I now have the following code:
% Define arguments
arg(1..10).

% Define attacks
att(4,7).
att(3,10).
att(3,9).
att(7,9).
att(9,2).
att(10,5).
att(5,2).
att(5,4).
att(2,3).
att(3,1).

out(X) :- arg(X), not in(X).

% Conflict-free rule
in(X) :- arg(X), not out(X).
% Contraint => no att(X, Y) in in/1 
:- in(X), in(Y), att(X, Y).

defended(X) :- att(Z, X), in(Y), att(Y, Z).
defended(X) :- not att(_, X), in(X).

:- in(X), not defended(X).

% Define when an argument is attacked by 'in'
attacked(Z) :- att(Y, Z), in(Y).

% Define when an argument is not defended
not_defended(X) :- att(Z, X), not attacked(Z).

% An argument is acceptable if it is defended
acceptable(X) :- arg(X), not not_defended(X).

% Ensure all acceptable arguments are included in 'in'
:- acceptable(X), not in(X).

Running this with Clingo, I get the following models:
set 1: out(1) out(2) in(3) out(4) in(5) in(7) out(9) out(10) in(6) in(8)
set 2: out(1) out(2) out(3) out(4) out(5) out(7) out(9) out(10) in(6) in(8)
The only correct answer in this case is the first answer, as the set 2 is a subset of set 1.
Any help is appriciated! Thanks!

you can try with weak constraints and associating each atom a weight/penalty
